# Problem when working with a sum over Bernoulli Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, bernoulli-numbers

Continuing my search of an integral expression for the sequence:

$$a_s=\sum_{n=0}^s {s \choose n} \frac{B_n}{n!}$$

(Where $B_n$ is the $n$th Bernoulli Number, $B_1$ is taken to be $\frac{1}{2}$ and $s$ must be a positive integer, see [my other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2345540/346773)) I came across the following development, which may be incorrect, since there is numerical evidence to think so. I would be interested in finding the flaw and trying to correct it (if possible) to get a correct result.

Let's start by pointing out the fact that, by the definition of binomial coefficient:

$$\sum_{n=0}^s {s \choose n} \frac{B_n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {s \choose n} \frac{B_n}{n!}$$

Then, since:

$${s \choose n}= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-π}^π e^{itn}(1+e^{it})^s \, dt$$

We have that:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{-π}^π e^{itn}(1+e^{it})^s \, dt \frac{B_n}{n!}$$

Up to here, everything seems to work fine.

Then, as the sum is absolutely convergent for positive integer $s$, say

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left | \int_{-π}^π \frac{B_n}{n!} e^{itn}(1+e^{it})^s \, dt \right | <\infty$$

We are allowed to interchange the sum and the integral operators (by the Fubini/Tonelli theorems, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/83747/346773) other question) to get:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-π}^π (1+e^{it})^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{itn} \frac{B_n}{n!} \, dt$$

By the Generating Function of Bernoulli Numbers, and since for any complex $z$ and integer $n$, $e^{zn}=(e^z)^n$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{itn} \frac{B_n}{n!}=\frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{-e^{it}}}$$

So that our original function/sequence can be expressed as:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-π}^π (1+e^{it})^s \frac{e^{it}}{1-e^{-e^{it}}} \, dt$$

The problem is that, fom example, setting $s=3$ in our original sequence (the sum), we would get $a_3=\frac{11}{4}$, but the integral will equal $1$. This error continues for all other values of $s$ computed.

Any help with this? Where is the flaw and how could it be solved?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you numerically checked each step? That is always a good way to go when you end up with a weird numerical answer. Find the step where numerics start to go astray

Comment: @Brevan I have checked up to the sentence "Up to here, everything seems to work fine" by using Wolfram alpha. From there on, the only step I can check is the last one, which gives an erroneous result

Comment: I would also want to know what is the precise error there, to understand the concept behind it and avoid future similar errors

Comment: I'll check this out later in Mathematica or something. I usually use simpler numeric tools, but none I generally use have the Bernoulli Numbers :/

Comment: I do not know about Mathematica, since I do not own that program, but at least in Wolfram Alpha the command is called NorlundB

Comment: ?? At least in English, Wolfram Alpha commands are the same as they would be in Mathematica (though wolfram Alpha has far less). In Mathematica this would be the command [BernoulliB](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BernoulliB.html)

Comment: Are you using NorlundB in order to get $B_1 = 1/2$? I would think NorlundB still uses $B_1 = -1/2$... That's what the documentation seems to say at least

Comment: NorlundB gives you the Bernoulli polynomial, so that $B_n$ would be NorlundB[n,1,1]

Comment: Ok. Be aware that Mathematica has $B_1 = -1/2$ though, which seems to contradict your post

Comment: Your definition for the Binomial Coefficient is incorrect, it should be $e^{-itn}$, see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/07/01/) for instance.

Comment: @Paul but, since $n$ is an integer, can't we say in this case that $e^{int}=e^{itn}=(e^{it})^n$?

Comment: That is a true statement, but, in the integral representation of the Binomial Coefficient, the $e^{itn}$ should be $e^{-itn}$, which are not equivalent.

Comment: Oh God, the minus sign. Thanks, I will correct it and repair my post as soon as possible

Comment: There does not seem to be any error [here](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F%282π%29%29∫%28%281%2Be%5E%28i*t%29%29%5E3*e%5E%28-i*t%29%2F%281-e%5E%28-e%5E%28-it%29%29%29%29dt+from+-π+to+π)

Comment: I have re-re-checked my original notes and you were right, at the middle of that mess I missed the $-$ sign. Thank you very much and sorry for my stupid mistake.

Comment: I have deleted the missign signs from the question so that you can add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the correct integral representation for the binomial coefficients is given by:
$$
{s \choose n}= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-π}^π e^{-itn}(1+e^{it})^s \, dt
$$
With this change, all of the results are accurate.